# Several missing permissions on GCP Console after account signup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Yesterday, I signed up for a Google Cloud Account. Since I want to link the user access with our own identity platform, I followed the instructions from this article:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/using-your-existing-identity-management-system-with-google-cloud-platform

I got as far as the account is created but in the GCP Console, on several screens, I get errors of missing permissions to view things, let alone change things. Here is an example:

[image: GCP Console Errors]

I was the one who created the account and in IAM I am listed as the Organization Administrator. How come I am missing so much permissions? Who within Google Cloud Support is listening/reading this and is able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug that needs to be fixed. As the Owner, you can add any roles that you need to your account. Neither the Owner nor the Organization Administrator have all roles assigned. You can, however, add desired roles to grant your identity more permissions. Consult the documentation for permissions assigned to each role. Then add the required roles to your identity (email address).

However, I recommend that you do not use an account with Owner or Organization Admin roles. Lock that identity in your safe after creating several new identities that use the principles of least privilege and have MFA enabled.

Comment: I understand completely to not use this account for too much purposes. I'm disappointed that the Organization Administrator doesn't even have "*.list" access on all matters in the Console.